# Constrain JFrame to single screen in a multi-monitor environment

Tags: java, applet, jframe, multiple-monitors

I am working on a web applet and have run into an issue. If a user is using Windows classic theme with a multi-screen environment and said user attempts to move a JFrame from one monitor to another Java will hang. I have been unable to find a solution to this issue, so as a workaround I wanted to see if there is any way I can prevent the user from moving a JFrame to a different monitor.  Is there a way to constrain window movement?